# Proof that primitive cells all have the same area?

Tags: geometry

Given some area that can tile 2d space and which contains 1 point of a lattice and given a second area that also only contains 1 lattice point and can tile the whole space how can i prove they are equal areas?

If one was larger it would overlap with itself, if it were smaller it wouldn't be able to tile the space. it's intuitively obvious but i have a hard time formalizing it because it's true that you could have separate tilings where the tiles are different sizes, but something about the fact that they each capture only one lattice point forbids this.

Comment: This is equivalent to the statement *"A tessellating shape that captures exactly one regular lattice point each when tessellating a plane has the same area as a cell of that lattice."* If the area was smaller, then assigning exactly one shape for each lattice point would leave uncovered areas, so the shape would not tessellate the plane.  If the area of the shape was greater, then assigning exactly one shape for each lattice point would cause overlaps, in which case the shape would not tessellate the plane either.  Unfortunately, me no mathematician, and cannot tell if this is a proof.

Comment: yes, thank you that's basically what ive been trying to put into better words. i think that is sufficient